# Vertx config with spring-config-server: unknown configuration store implementation: spring-config-server

Tags: vert.x

I would like to fetch my config from a spring cloud config server as described in https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-config/java/#_spring_config_server_store

Used imports:

```
import io.vertx.config.ConfigRetrieverOptions;
import io.vertx.config.ConfigStoreOptions;
import io.vertx.core.DeploymentOptions;
import io.vertx.core.VertxOptions;
import io.vertx.core.buffer.Buffer;
import io.vertx.core.dns.AddressResolverOptions;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.reactivex.config.ConfigRetriever;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx;
```

// relevant section:

```
    final ConfigStoreOptions storeOptions = new ConfigStoreOptions()
            .setType("spring-config-server")
            .setConfig(new JsonObject().put("url", "url-to-server"));

    final ConfigRetrieverOptions options = new ConfigRetrieverOptions()
            .addStore(storeOptions);
```

I use maven to build the jar and I can run the application in IntelliJ. The Jar contains all needed dependencies. However if I start the jar via CLI "java -jar articfact.jar" I get the following Error:

> 2020-01-17 10:54:04.121 INFO  [main] c.e.Runner
>   - Bootstrapping application... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown configuration store
>   implementation: spring-config-server (known implementations are:
>   [event-bus, file, json, http, env, sys, directory])   at
>   io.vertx.config.impl.ConfigRetrieverImpl.(ConfigRetrieverImpl.java:111)
>     at io.vertx.config.ConfigRetriever.create(ConfigRetriever.java:53)
>     at
>   com.example.Runner.main(Runner.java:41)

Im using Vertx version 3.8.4

Comment: did you add the dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Available config stores are found using the Java Service Loader utility. It means that the service loader will look for all files in the classpath like:

```
META-INF/services/io.vertx.config.spi.ConfigStoreFactory
```

These files contain the names of the available config store factories.

Since you build a FAT jar, it is likely that your build process keeps only the core service file and drops the service file that comes with the spring config server module.

You must configure your build to merge the content of all these files.

The Vert.x Maven plugin [does it by default](https://reactiverse.io/vertx-maven-plugin/#resource-combination), but you can also do it with the Maven shade plugin:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
              <resource>META-INF/services/io.vertx.core.spi.VerticleFactory</resource>
            </transformer>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
              <resource>META-INF/services/io.vertx.config.spi.ConfigStoreFactory</resource>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```